# Android: How Can I Implement onActivityResult() Method in RecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, onactivityresult, android-adapterview

I am trying upload an image from `RecyclerViewAdapter`.

How Can I Implement `onActivityResult()` Method in `RecyclerViewAdapter`?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340703/super-onactivityresult-inside-adapter-class-android

Comment: any other solution??